# Как "перевернуть таблицу" в JS(HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Когда с сервера на мой сайт приходит некая информация, то JS записывает эту информацию, и передаёт её в HTML таблицу. И каждая новая порция информации записывается в новую строку таблицы. НО информация записывается по убыванию, то есть самая свежая информация лежит в самом низу, а должно быть наоборот. Как это исправить?
[image: Фото]

```js
 arr1[count] = typeb;   //  тип нажатия
 arr2[count] = date;    // дата
 arr3[count] = clock;   // время
 arr4[count] = devaddr; // адресс(DevAddr)
 count++;           // когда приходит информация, к count прибавляется 1


var html = '<table border="1" cellpadding="3">';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<th>Тип нажатия</th>';
  html += '<th>Дата</th>';
  html += '<th>Время</th>';
  html += '<th>DevAddr</th>';
  html += '</tr>';
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
{
 html += '<tr>';
 html += '<td>' + arr2[i] + '</td>'; 
 html += '<td>' + arr3[i] + '</td>';
 html += '<td>' + arr1[i] + '</td>';
 html += '<td>' + arr4[i] + '</td>';
 html += '</tr>';
 

}
html += '</table>';
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html; // вывод в html
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: А не проще это на самом сервере и делать?

Comment: `for(var i = arr1.length; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: reverse() к своему массиву допиши

Comment: @splash58, в ответ запишите)